# Cannot find symbol of xml file animation

Tags: java, android-studio, android-animation

I need help. It says:
error: cannot find symbol  fruitImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myfruits);
^
symbol:   variable myfruits
location: class drawable

----------------------Here is the code----------------------

```
myfruits.xml (located at drawable)

<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/img_grapes" android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/img_lemon" android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/img_orange" android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/img_pear" android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/img_strawberry" android:duration="200"/>
</animation-list>
```

---------------MainActivity------------------

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView fruitImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFruit);
        fruitImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myfruits);
        fruitAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) fruitImage.getBackground();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the explanation.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable

In your code, you have to change the myfruits.xml.

```
<animation-list android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="false">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/img_grapes" android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/img_lemon" android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/img_orange" android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/img_pear" android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/img_strawberry" android:duration="200"/>
</animation-list>
```

-----Main activity---

```
ImageView fruitImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFruit);
fruitImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myfruits);
AnimationDrawable fruitAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) fruitImage.getBackground();
fruitAnimation.start();
```

Comment: Yes! I just solved my own problem. I created a new xml file called it "anim" copy and paste the xml code from myfruits to the new file and it works. Thanks!!!